# GDM Xorg launching behavior on 16.04 vs 18.04

Tags: gnome, xorg, lightdm, gdm, 18.04

I'm testing out Ubuntu 18.04 in preparation for it's launch to make sure certain software and configuration will still work on it when I upgrade, and i've noticed a discrepency in how GDM spawns GNOME/Xorg on 18.04 vs GDM or LightDM on 16.04.

On 16.04, whatever display is launched launches as a child process of the DM, so if I run `systemctl stop lightdm` (or gdm), Unity/Xorg dies with it. If I do the same on 18.04, GNOME sticks around, but GDM stops. Is there a setting to make GDM on 18.04 launch GNOME as a child process instead of (presumably) disowning it?

Thanks in advance!